# Is it possible to export a Blender f-curve noise modifier to another program?

Tags: modifiers, fcurves

I have a Blender background that looks like a stone wall illuminated by a flickering candle. The light source was made to "flicker" by putting a single keyframe at the light source's Energy Value, at frame 1, and going to the Graph Editor view and adding an f-curve noise modifier to it.... looks great... But now I want to have a green-screened actor in the foreground, and I want to have his lighting to flicker in the exact same way as the Blender light source. I don't know how to composite video in Blender, so ..... is it possible to somehow export the noise modifier's curve to use in another program? (This post has been altered since receiving the comments below.) Need help. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems about settings in Premiere. The values in Blender can be easily read from the noise modifier's settings.

Comment: You can do the compositing in blender, and use a **driver**, so that the brightness or the foreground element uses the same settings you used for the background.

Comment: You can bake the curve to keyframes either with *sample keyframes* or [*bake action*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/actions.html#bake-action), however I don't know what kind of animation premier can import. Would that help at all?